# How to disable submit button after jquery success function

Tags: jquery

Following is my jquery code which get the confirm login message in text format from php page and and then I redirect user to secure aria. Here I'm doing anther thing that is when "success" message appear I'm updating the database that user are  is loging now with time and date.

so after shwoing success message If i press the submit button sevral time then database is updating several time. That's why I want to disable the submit button after success message showing.

But Following code is not working. Do you know why ?

```
<script>
    $('#logining').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'loginProcess.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',      

   success: function (data) {

        $('#info2').html('');
        $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
          if(key !== 'error') {
            $('#info2').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');  
          }  
        });    
        if( ! data.error) {
         setTimeout(function () {
         $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true); 
         window.location.href = "login/index.php"; 
    },   2000); 
        }

   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: try `.prop()` insteaed of `attr()`

Comment: what will happen if the user clicks twice before the first request comes back

Comment: @kennypu Ok..I'm trying it.

Comment: @ArunPJohny If user clicks twice then database update twice but login is successful.

Comment: @kennypu if i use `.prop()` then it's don't send ajax request to php page. So that I can't login or register.

Comment: I don't understand your logic, but in order to disable a button, you need to do `$('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: @msound It's not disabling..it's still click able after success message show.